# how to test blackberry application on windows - Any free emulators?

Tags: blackberry

I have a blackberry app that I need to test on windows NOT on blackberry. Are there any free emulators that I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Research in Motion delivers several Device Simulators here

[Blackberry Simulator Downloads](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477)

Trackwheel / Trackball Devices are using usually up to OS Version 4.5 and Touch Devices 4.7+

Comment: I downloaded one of them. But I'm confused as in, There is this small company that developed an app for us. I need to test that App now on the simulator I just downloaded. Do you think I can download the app to simulator as the way I download it on actual Blackberry? I mean connecting to At&t or verizon network like that. you know what I mean?

Comment: yes, you can. Start up the MDS Simulator (for the Internet Connection) and open the URL in the devices browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Blackberry.com](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477) ?

Comment: Why the down vote?  The OP wanted to know if there were any emulators?  I gave them the link.